# Validate only visible fields with HTML form validation?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two group of form fields and in each group there are some fields with required attribute. However, depends on what user selects one group might be hidden and those fields should not be included in HTML form validation. So far if I have only one visible container in the form and I populate all required fields my form won't submit. Those hidden fields are still required for some reason.

Is there a way to exclude those fields from validation?

Here is example:

```js
var checkbox = $('.account-type');
checkbox.on('change', function() {
  var checked = false;

  checkbox.each(function() {
    checked = checked || $(this).is(':checked');
  });

  checkbox.prop('required', !checked);
});

$('.frm-Submit').on('submit', submitAdminFrm);

function submitAdminFrm(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevnts default form submit.
  alert('Submit form!');
}
```

```html
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form name="frmSave" id="frmSave" class="frm-Submit" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label" for="fname"><span class="label label-primary">First Name:</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frm_firstname" id="frm_firstname" placeholder="Enter First Name" maxlength="50" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label" for="lname"><span class="label label-primary">Last Name:</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frm_lastname" id="frm_lastname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" maxlength="50" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label" for="type"><span class="label label-primary">Account Type:</span></label>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label for="user">
          <input type="checkbox" name="frm_isuser" id="frm_isuser" class="account-type" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#user-account" required> 
          <span class="label label-default">User</span>
      </label>
      <label for="staff">
          <input type="checkbox" name="frm_isstaff" id="frm_isstaff" class="account-type" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#staff-account" required> 
          <span class="label label-info">Staff</span>
       </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="user-account" class="collapse">
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label class="control-label" for="active"><span class="label label-default">Active User:<span></label>
      <select class="form-control" name="frmSaveaccount_activeuser" id="frmSaveaccount_activeuser" required>
        <option value="">-- Select the option --</option>
        <option value="0">No</option>
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="staff-account" class="collapse">
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label class="control-label" for="activestaff"><span class="label label-info">Active Staff:<span></label>
      <select class="form-control" name="frmSaveaccount_activestaff" id="frmSaveaccount_activestaff" required>
        <option value="">-- Select the option --</option>
        <option value="0">No</option>
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
      <button type="submit" name="frmSaveaccount_submit" id="frmSaveaccount_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

How can I prevent fields inside of the hidden container from being validated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since both check boxes are off by default, add `disabled` to the inputs (selects) inside both divs. Then all you have to do is, inside `.change()`, toggle that `disabled` property according to the corresponding check box's state.

```js
var checkbox = $('.account-type');

checkbox.on('change', function() {
  var checked = false;

  checkbox.each(function() {
    checked = checked || $(this).is(':checked');
  });

  checkbox.prop('required', !checked);
  
  $('div'+$(this).data('target') + ' :input').prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'));
});

$('.frm-Submit').on('submit', submitAdminFrm);

function submitAdminFrm(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevnts default form submit.
  alert('Submit form!');
}
```

```html
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form name="frmSave" id="frmSave" class="frm-Submit" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label" for="fname"><span class="label label-primary">First Name:</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frm_firstname" id="frm_firstname" placeholder="Enter First Name" maxlength="50" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label" for="lname"><span class="label label-primary">Last Name:</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frm_lastname" id="frm_lastname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" maxlength="50" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label" for="type"><span class="label label-primary">Account Type:</span></label>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label for="user">
          <input type="checkbox" name="frm_isuser" id="frm_isuser" class="account-type" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#user-account" required> 
          <span class="label label-default">User</span>
      </label>
      <label for="staff">
          <input type="checkbox" name="frm_isstaff" id="frm_isstaff" class="account-type" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#staff-account" required> 
          <span class="label label-info">Staff</span>
       </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="user-account" class="collapse">
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label class="control-label" for="active"><span class="label label-default">Active User:<span></label>
      <select disabled class="form-control" name="frmSaveaccount_activeuser" id="frmSaveaccount_activeuser" required>
        <option value="">-- Select the option --</option>
        <option value="0">No</option>
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="staff-account" class="collapse">
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label class="control-label" for="activestaff"><span class="label label-info">Active Staff:<span></label>
      <select disabled class="form-control" name="frmSaveaccount_activestaff" id="frmSaveaccount_activestaff" required>
        <option value="">-- Select the option --</option>
        <option value="0">No</option>
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
      <button type="submit" name="frmSaveaccount_submit" id="frmSaveaccount_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```